# Unpredictable behavior in form validation with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

I'm completing some exercises from a javascript course (they are only meant for practice, I don't have to send my solutions) and when I'm trying to do a custom validation using regular expressions, capturing the submit event. The problem is that, if I enter an invalid input the first time, sometimes even if I correct it the custom validity message keeps showing up, and the console.log that show how many times the user tried to submit the form doesn't work, as if the submit event didn't even happen (for example: 1st input: "a", 2nd input: "aa", the custom validity message shows up and nothing can be loaded to the console, as if the submit event didn't even happen,but if I enter a valid input the first time, the error dissapears). I don't know if the way to solve this problem is to add an event listener for the blur event of the input and remove the custom validity there if necessary. A part of the code looks something like this (I added changes, the original one was simpler and had even more problems):

````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Example of form validation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Enter your user data</legend>
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Example: John Doe">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <button>Continue</button>
        </form>
        <script>

        let form = document.querySelector("form")
        let i = 0

        form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
            i++
            console.log(`You tried to submit this form ${i} times`)
            e.preventDefault()
            let input_name = document.querySelector("#name")
            let value = input_name.value
            let words = [value.split(" ")[0], value.split(" ")[1]]
            let words_joined = words[1] ? words[0] + " " + words[1] : words[0] // this ugly conditional statement prevents the program from joining a string with an undefined value
            let regex = /^\w{2,}(\s+\w{2,})*$/
            let matches = words_joined.match(regex)?.length
            try {                  
                if(matches){
                    handleSuccess.call(input_name)
                } else {
                    let err_msg = `You must enter 1 or 2 words with at least 2 characters each`
                    input_name.setCustomValidity(err_msg)
                    throw new Error(err_msg)
                }
            } catch (err){
                handleError.call(form, err) /// I prefer to send to both handlers the apropiate "this"
            }
        })

        function handleError(err){
            console.log(err)
        }

        function handleSuccess(){
            this.setCustomValidity(``)
            this.classList.add(`success`)
            console.log(`The input with the id "${this.id}" is valid`)
            this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.submit() // submits the form
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>```

If I remove the setCustomValidity() function everywhere, the problem dissapears, but that isn't very practical. At least it seems like that is the root of the problem.
````

Comment: I think it doesn't, I can barely understand parts of the code shown in the answer to that question so perhaps it could help but I can't really tell, but thanks!

Comment: Hi, I was going through  your code, what is this valor in else section 
**valor = words[0] + words[1]**
it hasn't declared anywhere.

Comment: Long story short, remove the `g` in `/(\w{2})+/g`. (So just `let regex = /(\w{2})+/`.)

Comment: solved the "valor" thing, I forgot to translate that part and since I still don't use "use strict" it was creating a global variable.

Comment: Also if `.match()` doesn't find a match, it will return `null`, so you might want to place the result in a variable and check if it is `null` before you check the `length`.

Comment: perhaps if I access the length property using "?." that won't be a problem, since null is falsy

Comment: @SebastianCharras I find it a bit difficult to decipher what kind of input should be allowed exactly, [but if I try to use your current code](https://jsfiddle.net/x2y3r4h5/) (and comment out the submit line for convenience), entering `aa a` and then `aa aa` gives me valid two times.

Comment: I tryed removing the all the "setCustomValidity() " and the problem dissapeared, but it isn't practical. It seems like I didn't use that function properly, so I will look again how it should be used and post the solutio if I found one

Comment: According to the exercise, I need to validate that the input with the id of "name" has 1 or 2 words written in it, each one being 2 or more characters long. I added the "g" again because it wouldn't validate the value properly.

Comment: @SebastianCharras Ah my bad. Then removing the `g` indeed breaks things. Though you can check that in one single regex: `^\w{2,}(\s+\w{2,})?$`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/h91x7urv/

Comment: Nice! I added that regex and changed some other things to the code, I'm editing the post a lot (I know I shouldn't, but my code was even worse that I thought), and now the problem happens consistently, so clearly I have to solve the customvalidity error and using a variable instead of several regexp matches was also a needed change (that made it a consistent problem, before that it was a little unpredictable perhaps because of the lastIndex problem). So, instead of 2 error, now there is only 1.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved thanks to the help of Ivar. I made some changes to the original code (those are reflected on the original post, sorry for not posting them anywhere else), and added the following lines:

````
            let value = input_name.value
            let words = [value.split(" ")[0], value.split(" ")[1]]
            let words_joined = words[1] ? words[0] + " " + words[1] : words[0] // this ugly conditional statement prevents the program from joining a string with an undefined value
            // words_joined only contains the first 1 or 2 words
            let regex = /^\w{2,}(\s+\w{2,})*$/
            let matches = words_joined.match(regex)?.length
            try {                  
                if(matches){
                    value = words_joined // if there were more than 2 words, only the first 2 remain in the value of the input with the id "name"
                    handleSuccess.call(input_name, "don't submit")
                } else {
                    let err_msg = `You must enter 1 or 2 words with at least 2 characters each`
                    input_name.setCustomValidity(err_msg)
                    throw new Error(err_msg)
                }
            } catch (err){
                handleError.call(form, err) /// I prefer to send to both handlers the apropiate "this"
            }
        })

        function handleError(err){
            console.log(err)
        }

        function handleSuccess(shouldSubmit){
            this.setCustomValidity(``)
            this.classList.add(`success`)
            console.log(`The input with the id "${this.id}" is valid`)
            if(shouldSubmit != "don't submit") this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.submit() // submits the form
        }```

the last two functions are almost equal to the ones written in the original question, but with the addition of the "shouldSubmit" parameter and a conditional statement for the last one. Basically, the unpredictability of the error seems to have been caused by how regular expressions with the "g" flag work in js, and it was solved by assigning the return value of the match() function to a variable and using that variable on the rest of the scope. And the main problem, that error showing up even after correcting an invalid input, was ocurring because the custom validity was showing up between submits. Now that an event listener for the "change" event of the input is added, this is corrected. Thanks for the help!
````